# Netbeans blank window in Windows 7

Tags: java, php, netbeans, windows-7

I am using windows 7 32bit version and I am using Netbeans IDE 7.4 for PHP programming. Today I started my netbeans IDE and it just showed only a blank screen. All my projects are missing and it is just only a blank screen.
[image: Refer image]

Have you guys faced this problem? What has happened to my IDE ?

P:S - I am quite sure that I did not change any directories or I did nothing for my projects.

Answer (score 0):

check this menu

Window => Show View => PHP Explorer

[image]

OR

you have choose the correct workspace

goto

File => Switch Workspace => choose path

Comment: -Thanks, but I selected  Windows ->Reset Windows to get the old state of the window. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me once before, and I had to reconfigure my view panels. I think it was because a glitch caused the workspace to be lost by the IDE.

Check that your workspace is the same as usual.